# PowerShell RoboCopy Specific Files From 1 Server to Another Server

Tags: powershell, robocopy

Consider a scenario:

1. Server A has one File_Folder where there are 100K + files, and some files might be super huge
2. I have a .csv File for each user(which has a complete set of files list to be copied from Server A File_Folder) to Server B(where there is a directory for this each User)

My logic is 
1) Read each CSV files for each user 1 by 1
2) put the list for RoboCopy to copy files from Server A to Server B each user folder
3) it works for me but it is super slow. I want to make it faster.

Note:
Mandatory to use PowerShell

My Code look like this

```
$Get_CSV_File_INFO = @(Get-Content $Full_CSV_Path )
$SourcePath = "z:\"

foreach($a in $Get_CSV_File_INFO)
    {

    if($a -match '.zip')
     {
     $RS_Report_Name.add($a) |Out-Null
     }
}

$RS_Report_Name | % { Robocopy $SourcePath  $path $_} | Out-Null
```

## Destionation Path is like Y:\UserA, Y:\UserB etc.....

Any suggestion might help.

I am not logging and not showing any output; it improved the speed 
but still Copying total of "2.57 MB" files took around 9 minutes which is not good in a real life scenario.

Comment: Are you running this on Server A, Server B, or a totally separate box?  Based on your `$sourcePath` being "z:\" I assume both Server A and B are remote from where you run the script.  If so, you're copying content from Server A to B through your local machine.  That's two sequential network hops.  Changing your pattern to invoke a copy directly from A to B should be considerably faster.  Especially if your script-running machine is on a slower link compared to A->B.

Comment: it a good idea to run on the destination server instead of host to make things more faster 

this tip is really good

Comment: Did that solve your problem?  I can post it up as an answer.  If I need to run on a third machine, I'll typically invoke-command to Server A, then within the script block:  map a drive to server B with explicit credentials, copy from A to B.

Comment: I was thinking to run the script from Server B and map a drive on server A. It will definitely makes things fast for. but its not a complete solution as RoboCopy Command acting slow in below case
$RS_Report_Name | % { Robocopy $SourcePath  $path $_} | Out-Null
i also need an alternative way of it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$RS_Report_Name` is an array filtered to only the files you want to copy changing the `robocopy` to copy all files instead of one by one should have a big impact.

```
robocopy $SourcePath $path $RS_Report_Name
```

If that still exceeds the max command length, split the array into smaller groups say 10-50   and run `Robocopy` on each.

Comment: you solution is good but getting this error Program 'Robocopy.exe' failed to run: The filename or extension is too long

Comment: as i Mentioned $RS_Report_Name will have a big list of file Names

Comment: Also out of 100K plus files I only need to copy few 100 files 
not all of them

Comment: Create an array filter to the files you do want to copy and replace `$RS_Report_name` with it... Your example seems to indicate that `$RS_Report_name` is already filtered  

If that still exceeds the max, split the array into smaller groups say 10-50   and run `robocopy` on each.

Update the answer with these details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  Matthew Wetmore  for the suggestion to run PowerShell Script on Destination server and Thanks Travis for the Suggestions to divide the arraylist

$Report_array2 = $Report_array[$Initial_Counter .. $Counter]

Robocopy "$SourcePath"  "$path" $Report_array2 /MT /Z  |out-Null

Also I use /MT for Multi Threading and /Z(Restart Mode) performance increased from Minutes to few Seconds